# initialize a member of a struct inside a function

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I'm connecting a function to a signal in gtk, I'm using a struct to pass multiple variables to the function

I want to initialize the value of a char array inside the function

here's my code so far:

```
struct new_button_data
{
  char name;
};

static struct new_button_data nb;
       g_signal_connect(new_button_dialog,"response",G_CALLBACK (add_new_button),&nb);


void add_new_button(GtkDialog *dialog, gint response_id, gpointer new_button)
{
  if (response_id==-5) //ok button pressed
  {
    strcpy(((char *)((struct new_button_data *) new_button)->name) , "test");
  }
}
```

I'mm trying to allocate a string obtained from a gtk widget to the new_button->name character array, and I'm getting a segfault as a result of running that code

how can I initialize its value inside the function?
thanks

Comment: Where is a "character array"?? And do not cast just for fun, but only if you really **know** all implications. If you don't, do not cast! And enable warnings, your compiler wants to kick butt.

Comment: also, this isn't *initialization*, it's *assignment*.

Comment: felix thanks for the info, Olaf, I had forgotten to declate as an array
can you point me to where I can read about the implications of casting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field you're trying to write to is of type `char`.  The `strcpy` function requires a `char *`.  You can't just cast a `char` to a `char *` and expect things to work.

If you know how big a name can be, you can define it as a char array:

```
#define NAME_LEN 100
struct new_button_data
{
  char name[NAME_LEN];
};
```

If you don't know the size, you can declare it as a `char *` and use `strdup` to create the memory for it and copy the string:

```
struct new_button_data
{
  char *name;
};

void add_new_button(GtkDialog *dialog, gint response_id, gpointer new_button)
{
  if (response_id==-5) //ok button pressed
  {
    ((struct new_button_data *) new_button)->name = strdup("test");
  }
}
```

You'll need to remember to call `free` on `name` when you're done with it.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a member

```
char name;
```

you can only hold one character in the `struct`. You cannot hold a string.

You need to use

```
char* name;
```

Allocate memory for `name` when you need to store the name.

Then, copy the name to `name`.

```
struct new_button_data
{
  char* name;
};
```

and then,

```
if (response_id==-5) //ok button pressed
{
  (struct new_button_data *) new_button)->name = malloc(5); // Make it large enough
  strcpy(((struct new_button_data *) new_button)->name , "test");
}
```

You'll need to remember to call `free` on the `name` when you don't need it.